# OdbcException was caught while firing the SQL query

Tags: c#, odbc

'admin_table_name' is string array containing the names of table which are taken as an input from text file and 'table_index' is the index of an array.so,while firing the query below,"admin_table_name[table_index]" is avoided by throwing 'OdbcException was caught' as an exception.what is the mistake i am making in the code? please help.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SHOW KEYS FROM " + admin_table_name[table_index] + " where Key_name = 'PRIMARY'";
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use ODBC? For most databases are native Drivers available.
Can you post the the complete String of the CommandText before executing the Reader?

Comment: OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection();
        OdbcCommand cmd; OdbcDataReader dr;connection = new OdbcConnection();
                         connection.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost ; Database =" + admin_databases[database_index] + "; Uid = root; Pwd=admin";

Comment: Have you checked in debug mode that all the variables (admin_databases[database_index] and admin_table_name[table_index]) are filled with the correct value?

Comment: I would recommend to use a native mysql Driver like:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: when i statically provide the data,no such exception is thrown but exception is thrown only when input is taken from file and then stored in an string array

Comment: I can't find mistakes in your posted code. Can you post the complete ODBCException?